# How do you say QR code?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen this question in a few places. A QR code (Quick Response code) is like a square "bar code" that you can scan with your phone. What is this called in Esperanto and how do you pronounce it?

[image: QR Code from Wikimedia]

Answer (score 10):

After reviewing the answers and discussions at the three links listed below, I have come the conclusion that "QR code" is sufficiently international to be directly translated into Esperanto.

- ***QR-kodo***
- ***ku-ro-kodo***

The name of the letter Q is *kuo*, and I would pronounce it without the final -o on *kuo*, using an even stress on *ku* and *ro* (so that it doesn't sound like *kuro-kodo*, a running code).

https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1418530

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

http://lernu.net/en/forumo/temo/11004

Comment: +1 for _ku-ro-kodo_

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I have already used and heard it used in practice, without even thinking that there might be alternatives. However, I would pronounce it ___kuo-ro-kodo___ with three stresses, to avoid any confusion. In rapid speech, the second stress becomes very weak.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call it *strekokodo* but if you want to be specific:

- Dudimensia strekokodo
- kurokodo

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strekokodo